# Исправить сглаживание изображения в javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, изображения

Здравствуйте, я отрисовываю изображение в ctx, предварительно отключив при этом сглаживание:

```
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

после чего растягиваю его

```
ctx.scale(4, 4);
```

получаю это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

откуда берется это и как его исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой браузер? .

Comment: @AlexeyTen Google Chrome

Comment: непонятно а зачем вы отключили сглаживание ?? не выключайте его или включите обратно после масштабирования

Comment: @ampawd Не помогло, если включить сглаживание - картинка получается очень размытой, а мне это не нужно - она должна быть пиксельной, без каких либо обводок или внутренних линий

Comment: а чего вы ещё ожидаете при масштабировании такого изображения с малым количеством точек ?

Comment: я бы попробывал в ручную интерполировать, но наврятли результат будет сильно лучше

Comment: @ampawd Вы хотите сказать, что нет способа вывести пиксельное изображение в canvas без потери качества?

Answer (score 0):

Решено. По какой-то колдунской причине изображение размывалось из-за маштаба страницы: 90% и 100% - все размыто, а на 80% и меньше - все отлично